# Regex pattern match in EXPECT script

Tags: regex, expect

I have an EXPECT script that monitors the http pid's on an IBMIHS server:

```
    ....
    send "ps -ef|grep htt|grep start|wc -l \r"
    expect {
       -re {.*(\d+).*} {

          set theNum $expect_out(1,string)
      }
    }

    puts "theNum = $theNum"

    if {$theNum > 8} {
      puts "it is ok"
    } else {
      puts "it is not ok"
    }
....
```

The `send "ps -ef|grep htt|grep start|wc -l \r"` generates:

> > send: sending "ps -ef|grep htt|grep start|wc -l \r" to { exp5 }
> >  Gate
> >     keeper glob pattern for '.*(\d+).*' is ''. Not usable, disabling the
> >     performance booster.
> >
> > expect: does "" (spawn_id exp5) match regular expression ".*(\d+).*"?
> >     (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no 
> >  ps -ef|grep htt|grep start|wc -l
> >
> > expect: does "ps -ef|grep htt|grep start|wc -l \r\n" (spawn_id exp5)
> >     match regular expression ".*(\d+).*"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes
> >     re=no 
> > ***11***
> >
> > expect: does "ps -ef|grep htt|grep start|wc -l \r\n**11**\r\n" (spawn_id
> >     exp5) match regular expression ".*(\d+).*"? (No Gate, RE only)
> >     gate=yes re=yes
>
> expect: set expect_out(0,string) "ps -ef|grep htt|grep start|wc -l
>   \r\n**11**\r\n" 
> expect: set expect_out(1,string) **"1"**  
>   expect: set
>   expect_out(spawn_id) "exp5"  expect: set expect_out(buffer) "ps
>   -ef|grep htt|grep start|wc -l \r\n**11**\r\n" 
>  theNum = 1 
>  it is not ok

The command line actually returns a number "**11**", but the `(\d+)` catches one **'1'** instead.

Your comments are appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the greediness of the leading `.*` -- because that slurps up as many characters as possible, the text remaining for the `(\d+)` part is the *last* digit.  Here's a demo where I also capture the leading ".*":

```
expect1.11> exp_internal 1
expect1.12> spawn sh -c {echo foo; echo 1234; echo bar}
spawn sh -c echo foo; echo 1234; echo bar
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {78523}
78523
expect1.13> expect -re {(.*)(\d+).*}
Gate keeper glob pattern for '(.*)(\d+).*' is ''. Not usable, disabling the performance booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp10) match regular expression "(.*)(\d+).*"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no
foo
1234
bar

expect: does "foo\r\n1234\r\nbar\r\n" (spawn_id exp10) match regular expression "(.*)(\d+).*"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "foo\r\n1234\r\nbar\r\n"
expect: set expect_out(1,string) "foo\r\n123"
expect: set expect_out(2,string) "4"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp10"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "foo\r\n1234\r\nbar\r\n"
```

Take note of what gets stored in "1,string" and "2,string"

The solution is to simplify your regex. If you just want to capture the *first* set of digits, use

```
expect -re {\d+}
set theNum $expect_out(0,string)
```

Or if you want to capture the first digits *that are the only chars on a line*:

```
expect -re {\r\n(\d+)\r\n}
set theNum $expect_out(1,string)
```

One lesson here is that you generally don't need to have leading and ending `.*` wildcards in your regular expression patterns: just focus on what you need to capture the text you want.

Comment: Glenn, Your solution works perfectly! like you answer style: clean and right on the point! thanks!